# Typescript does not recognize interface function expression tuples

Tags: typescript, function, tuples

I'm trying to call a function expression like this:

```
export default interface IUserManager {
    deleteUser: ((userId: string) => Promise<void>) | ((userName: string, userSurname: string, city: string) => Promise<void>
}
```

from a class which holds the interface instance:

```
import MyUserManager from "path/to/IUserManager.ts"

class CompanyProcessor {
    private myUserManager: IUserManager;

    public constructor() {
        this.myUserManager = new MyUserManager(); // MyUserManager implements IUserManager
    }

    public async deleteUser(userId: string): Promise<void> {
        await this.myUserManager.deleteUser(userid); // Expected 3 argument, but got 1. ts(2554)
    }
}
```

In VSCode, hovering over the function expression in IUserManager shows the tuple of functions. Hovering over the function call in CompanyProcessor shows only the largest function in the tuple. I've also noticed that making "userSurname" and "city" optional does work in CompanyProcessor, but doing this breaks the requirement of 3 properties, making it possible to only provide the first 2. It also does not seem to use the other functions in the tuple this way.

Example hover pop-up in the original situation:

```
(property) IUserManager.deleteUser: (userName: string, userSurname: string, city: string) => Promise<void>
```

Example hover pop-up when "userSurname" and "city" are optional:

```
(property) IUserManager.deleteUser: (userName: string, userSurname?: string, city?: string) => Promise<void> (+1 overload)
```

My TypeScript version is 4.7.4

Comment: You declared `IUserManager`, but using `MyUserManager`, is it ok? If you implements `IUserManager` in `MyUserManager`, there are no errors: http://shorturl.at/knUZ1

Comment: Oh you're right, my example code wasn't entirely correct. I'll correct the example, as I am referring to the IUserManager function from CompanyProcessor.

Comment: @Eugene But when there is only one argument (attempting to use the first "overload") it does not work.

Comment: Yeah I noticed I put something backwards, for that my apologies. The problem isn't with the leftmost function, but that it apparently always assumes the shape of the largest function expression. It does not accept `deleteUser(userId)` in this shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a union of functions. Instead you can use [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) to describe a function with multiple overloads:

```
deleteUser: {
    (userId: string): Promise<void>;
    (userName: string, userSurname: string, city: string): Promise<void>;
};
```

Comment: I tried this and it definitely is the way to go. Thank you!