# TypeScript Array Union Type in function parameters

Tags: typescript, union-types, function-parameter, type-definition

I have a union type of an Array of various specific lengths:

```
[ number ] | [ number, number ] | [ number, number, number, number ]
```

As you can see, there are requirements for an array with one element, two elements, or four elements.

I am trying to create an object which contains a function with one of these lengths. How do I write the type definition to allow for this?

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAm8BOBTK0De0C%20AoXwA9gHYQAu0ADioZSCgFya7TTFgC2j05SAlsQDmAGhbQwiVFCYJkaCKNYB3QkgDWTABTEArhwBGKJBCYBtNnsNJoAXWgAfaOd0Gjwi6%20t3Hzy249W7i6BAUa2AJTQALwAfOLEAJ642KZ2UU5iGGKs7FxMAEQAQoT6%20Yqs4pLyTMQoSnBVUJrh5cqqGtAAZjrEwGR8JNp%20xmahXuE1w8wVFUSkFOYcCQByUzajwWFpYxAA3PgzrKhkOkjE0EurntAAVNAAbNk4YtjlWTO53PmwEAAW9Akyk8JHJpGw6g1QRBmq1oCp1Exur1%20oNNiMnGMgsMsZ4cVYIkx9IRCPQwOd3oc5uQMZdsfFCGRfkYriEIIQuCz-Kg6GBgChOV4NnS0Xj-GjbOk0XsDodjqdzrTrlFlfTGcypgAyDU8dn8qbK9Lc8B8gX7GZ4VivTJPT4FACyfGAvzAKBAQJmIKkJnB9VkXphT3hHSRfQGxCGnm9vlxYwJsYpMypCwuKzpZIZTKQAtsQpj4u2Uv2TyOKBOZxT2bu6bVWeGZoqFpwohsQA)

Example:

```
const people: {
    name: string,
    address: Address,
    work: (numbers: [ number ] | [ number, number ] | [ number, number, number, number ]) => any
}[] = [
    {
        name: "Bob",
        address: new Address(),
        work: function(numbers: [ number ]): number {
            // Implementation returning number
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Ashley",
        address: new Address(),
        work: function(numbers: [ number, number, number, number ]): boolean {
            // Implementation returning boolean
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Michael",
        address: new Address(),
        work: function(numbers: [ number, number ]): number {
            // Implementation returning number
        }
    },
]
```

Currently, it's giving me the error:

[image: Error message]

Type '(numbers: [number]) => number' is not assignable to type '(numbers: [number] | [number, number] | [number, number, number, number]) => any'.
Types of parameters 'numbers' and 'numbers' are incompatible.
Type '[number] | [number, number] | [number, number, number, number]' is not assignable to type '[number]'.
Type '[number, number]' is not assignable to type '[number]'.
Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1.ts(2322)

------- Edit -------

I've applied a suggestion from the comments and made all the possible calls into separate function unions instead of an array union:

```
const people: {
    name: string,
    address: Address,
    work: ((numbers: [ number ]) => any) | ((numbers: [ number, number ]) => any) | ((numbers: [ number, number, number, number ]) => any)
}[] = [
```

When trying to now call a function from this array:

```
 people[1].work([2, 8, 6, 4])
```

It throws the following error now:

[image: Type number is not assignable to type never]

In VSCode I found out this is why:

"The intersection '[number] & [number, number] & [number, number, number, number]' was reduced to 'never' because property 'length' has conflicting types in some constituents."

Comment: `work: ((numbers: [ number ]) => any) | ((numbers: [ number, number ]) => any)`

Comment: What you want to do is define all of the possible functions, instead of 1 function that can handle everything

Comment: Interesting. This is indeed the solution, but I thought it wouldn't work (for this reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73389373/typescript-does-not-recognize-interface-function-expression-tuples). Please put your comment as an answer so I can set it as a valid answer.

Comment: Acually, I tried a bit more and it seems I still cannot call the functions. I get this error now: `The intersection '[number] & [number, number] & [number, number, number, number]' was reduced to 'never' because property 'length' has conflicting types in some constituents.`

Comment: You'll have to manually tell it the type of the function when calling it `(work as ((numbers: [ number ]) => any))([1])`, since typescript can't figure it out on it's own.

Comment: Or you can go back to your original definition for `work()`, but put the same union type for the `numbers` parameter on the implementation. Then in the implementation you'll have to check the length of the argument.

Comment: Can't I do something with Extract<T, U>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**
You need to use bivariance here

```js
class Address { }

type Tuple<
  N extends number,
  Item = number,
  Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
  > =
  (Result['length'] extends N
    ? Result
    : Tuple<N, Item, [...Result, number]>
  )


interface WorkFn {
  work(numbers: Tuple<1> | Tuple<2> | Tuple<4>): any
}

interface Person extends WorkFn {
  name: string,
  address: Address,
}

const people: Person[] = [
  {
    name: "Bob",
    address: new Address(),
    work(numbers: Tuple<1>) {
      const [myNumber] = numbers;

      return myNumber * 6
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Ashley",
    address: new Address(),
    work: function (numbers: Tuple<4>): boolean {
      const [myNumber, anotherNumber, someNumber, replaceNumber] = numbers;

      return myNumber === anotherNumber && someNumber === replaceNumber;
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Michael",
    address: new Address(),
    work: function (numbers: Tuple<2>): number {
      const [myNumber, anotherNumber] = numbers;

      return myNumber * anotherNumber;
    }
  },
]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAQgXm)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73508157/difference-between-and-in-typescript/73509395#73509395) you can find the difference between method type an arrow function type and about `bivariance`

Also, please be aware that it is not 100% safe

Comment: Not a bad answer, but unfortunately, it does not allow me to actually call these functions. Turns out TypeScript converts the parameter type to 'never': `The intersection '[number] & [number, number] & [number, number, number, number]' was reduced to 'never' because property 'length' has conflicting types in some constituents.`

Comment: @DubiousMaster my bad, fixed

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be to use a generic function to create the `people` array.

```
function createPeople<
  T extends {
    name: string,
    address: Address,
    work: ((numbers: [ number ]) => any) | ((numbers: [ number, number ]) => any) | ((numbers: [number, number, number, number]) => any)
  }[]
>(p: [...T]){
  return p
}

const people = createPeople([
  {
    name: "Bob",
    address: new Address(),
    work: function(numbers: [ number ]): number {
      const [ myNumber ]: [ number ] = numbers;

      return myNumber * 6
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Ashley",
    address: new Address(),
    work: function(numbers: [ number, number, number, number ]): boolean {
      const [ myNumber, anotherNumber, someNumber, replaceNumber ]: [ number, number, number, number ]= numbers;

      return myNumber === anotherNumber && someNumber === replaceNumber;
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Michael",
    address: new Address(),
    work: function(numbers: [ number, number ]): number {
      const [ myNumber, anotherNumber ]: [ number, number ] = numbers;

      return myNumber * anotherNumber;
    }
  },
])
```

TypeScript now knows what the callback of each index is. That makes the following calls strictly typed.

```
people[1].work([2, 8, 6, 4])
people[2].work([1, 2])
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAm8BOBTK0DeBfAUDgZgK4B2wALgJYD2x0wqYZKACilQA4goA8O00AFWgoAHk2LwYGPv2jEwAWxQAuaBDJIKxAOYAaGfzCJUUVQmRoI+2dADuVJAGtVAChfFCCgEYokEVQDacp4+SNAAugCU0AC8AHzQYMQAntEAPtBuHt6+-tBB2aG6wTlhUbEJSanQGVkhuYGFvsVNSC31bSWh5fGJKZEyWAHhOHEu7IEAdNMCUdL8qGSESLTsOLg4wDTq0OxsnCixdAxMrBxcLgEy87LySqoARABCVF4P1rJGFqZyKLZwxksLkiH349icqiIpEoNHcHTyBQ6EUiqlamAMsi2xB2QQUyQAckjwoEur4IkdWhAANx4GwLFBLFbQPGE0rQABU0AAbBjcPwsB8bvw7ipoA9YBAABZcZLvDFfEx5Yh-AHfCDA0F2BzOaBQ8jUYhw0oI0mdVrtUoW0LI1ReKhULhJdF0ujbMj5ZkEjrFJJUMiS3ysopqKhKIPNaCoThgYAocNlEnm01WiNo8IxU3U2l0xbLWgspExIt9P0BpDx6AAMkrIbDheLUfAsfjNJsfOgAuuGJFjwAshRgJKwCgQHKbArLKiVeZFRqMeCdXqYYbKYnvaabRuhZi3R6C5aS-7A0S1we0xT4TSMfTGfmvWzOb6j+WOq3ZO3O1E8HtzigAgBGcJJgXS4ACZigADmKLligAFi-H8DgCUCgJAgDihQyIgA)